# Vector element ID's C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, element

```
UserFile.open(cname + ".txt");
int numOfElements = name.size();

if (UserFile.is_open())
{
    name.push_back(cname);
    pass.push_back(cpass);
    posx.push_back(0);
    posy.push_back(0);
    id.push_back(numOfElements);

    std::cout << "Your player name has been registered successfully." << std::endl;
    UserFile << cname << ";" << cpass << ";" << "0" << ";" << "0";
}
```

I've gotten this far with adding players to vectors and even the numOfElements works correctly.. How can I read statistics of each player representing the player id as the nth element in the vector?
Example:

```
else if (userInput == "stats") // Ignore the else
{
    // Name is Allura. ID is stored too. Increments from 0 to work with the vector
    // What can I do to make a way of showing information only in that nth element (like element 0 if player id is 0) etc?
}
```

Comment: Are you storing the different properties (name, pass, pos) in different vectors? You really should have a single vector of structs; this is C++

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to find the index of the player with a given `id`?

Comment: Player 1 and 2 registers then logs in. Player 1 has 0 stored in the id vector and player 2 has 1 stored as id. Player 1 types stats. Don't want to show the stats of both players so I need the program to know which information to send. Now, because player 1 has 0 stored in the id vector, I need it to find the ID of that player and use it as the array index in the name vector. name[id]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to store a list of players, you should have a single vector of objects:

```
struct Player {
    std::string name, pass;
    int posx, posy;
    int id;
    // etc.
};

std::vector<Player> players;
```

To add a new player to this list, you can `push_back` a braced-init-list with all the properties:

```
players.push_back({cname, cpass, 0, 0, numOfElements /*, etc. */});
```

If you then want to find a player with a given `id` (or other property), use [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) (which finds the first element for which the given condition is true):

```
int id_to_find = ...;
auto iterator = std::find_if(players.begin(), players.end(), [&](const Player& p) {
    return p.id == id_to_find;
});
if (iterator == players.end()) {
    // the id wasn't found
} else {
    // the id was found
    // (*iterator) is a reference to the Player object in the vector
}
```

This uses a [lambda expression](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-lambda-expressions-the-nuts-and-bolts-of-functional-programming/) (like a lambda in Python or an anonymous function in JavaScript). If you're unfamiliar with how iterators work, look those up; in C++, they're almost always used instead of working with indices.

Comment: Thanks qxz! Yes, I've learned about iterators over the past few days and understand how to use them as a loop in both vectors and maps but I don't understand too much about the pointers at this time. When to use * or &? I've seen them used ambiguously. Also, why is the address pointer in brackets before the find_if player object like so-->   [&] ?

Comment: One more question as I've been studying alone.. If I am to go with your struct method, how could I define the struct in a Monster class? Is this where I use something like: 'void Monsters::monsterAttack(Players &player)', with the struct being the function parameters defined with &?

Comment: The `[&]` in the lambda is called the capture list; it defines what outside variables will be available inside the lambda. Using `&` means to capture all local variables by reference. This is needed to be able to use `id_to_find`. [The article I linked](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-lambda-expressions-the-nuts-and-bolts-of-functional-programming/) has a good explanation of the details of lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, `Player` is a type just like `int` or `std::string`, so you can pass a `Player` to a function like that: `void whatever(Player &player)`, `whatever(players[0])`, etc.